# How can I maintain my underscore template settings in plunker?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, plunker

I've been using plunker for about a month now. I was making a backbonejs plunker and I see that Underscore loses my template settings and falls back to ERB style templating whereas I would like the Mustache style syntax `{{ myData }}` . I am setting the value in my app.js (which I always do in my apps) but for some reason, it keeps changing back to ERB `<%=boo%>`. Can someone help me get my template setting straightened out?
[plunker using underscore templating](http://plnkr.co/edit/1X0Tn3?p=preview) you'll need to view the console output in chrome dev tools or firebug or equiv...

Thanks for any tips or tricks.  I tried

```
_.templateSettings = { 
   interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
   evaluate: /\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g
 };
```

when I `console.log(_.templateSettings)` in my app.js file right after setting, everything seems correct, but my templates aren't being processed. I can break inside a view and run the same console.log() and I see it has been switched back to ERB style. Does anyone know how to make my settings stick? Perhaps it's a plunker issue because I have used this method many times without a problem.

which usually does the trick. I even try...
    window._ = _;

Thanks for any help, tips, tricks, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have an order of execution problem. Your `app.js` says this:

```
var app = {
  init: function () {
    _.templateSettings = {
      interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
      evaluate: /\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g
    };
    window._ = _;
  },
  //...
```

so your template settings won't be applied until someone calls `app.init()`. If we have a look at one of your views in `main.js`, we'll see things like this:

```
Zurg.Views.AltContent = app.View.extend({
  #...
  template: _.template([...].join('')),
  #...
```

So your `_.template` call happens while `main.js` is being loaded and parsed but `app.init()` isn't called until later.

All you need to do is arrange for things to happen in this order:

1. Load the libaries (jQuery, Underscore, Backbone, ...)
2. Adjust the `_.templateSettings` to use your delimiters.
3. Load your views.

If you move the `_.templateSettings` to outside `app.init`:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    evaluate: /\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g
};

var app = {
  init: function () {
    // Whatever you really need to initialize things goes here...
  },
  //...
```

then everything should work out. BTW, your `window._ = _;` trick wasn't doing anything useful so I took it out. And you should include an `escape` regex in `_.templateSettings` too, you might not need it but completeness is good.

Comment: Thanks mu. I figured it was a timing type issue. Awesome!